# Why is gremlin outputting "null" at the of my script?

Tags: groovy, gremlin

I'm learning to use Gremlin and am just starting to make basic graphs using the command line.   I've learned that I can put this into a script, which is basically just a bunch of groovy (which I'm also just becoming familiar with).  I run the following script, and everything works great except I get `==> null' once the script is done running (in addition to all of the correct messages regarding the nodes/edges that are made).   What did I do wrong?

```
graph = TinkerGraph.open()
g = graph.traversal()
//The nodes
curCharge = graph.addVertex(id, 1, label, "Topic", "name","Current")
pow = graph.addVertex(id, 2, label, "Topic", "name","power")
powFromNRG = graph.addVertex(id, 3, label, "Topic", "name","powerFromNRG")
NRGFromPower = graph.addVertex(id, 4, label, "Topic", "name","NRGFromPower")
powFromVI = graph.addVertex(id,5,label,"Topic","name","powerFromIV")
powInRes = graph.addVertex(id,6,label,"Topic","name","powerInResistors")
passSign = graph.addVertex(id,7,label,"Topic","name","passiveSignPower")
ohmLaw = graph.addVertex(id,8,label,"Topic","name","ohmsLaw")

//the pre-requisite edges
pow.addEdge("prereq",powFromNRG)
pow.addEdge("prereq",NRGFromPower)
pow.addEdge("prereq",powFromVI)
powFromVI.addEdge("prereq",passSign)
passSign.addEdge("prereq",powInRes)
ohmLaw.addEdge("prereq",powInRes)

//just some test queries
nL = g.V().has("name","passiveSignPower").inE("prereq").outV()
if(nL != null)
    println "Hey!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gremlin Console returns the result of each line that gets executed. In your case, the last line executed is `println "Hey!"` which is a `void` method, so it returns `null`.

Here's the result that you're seeing:

```
gremlin> if(nL != null)
......1>     println "Hey!"
Hey!
==>null
```

You can see that `Hey!` was printed out to the screen, but `null` is the result.

If you change your script to simply return the string `Hey!`, you can avoid getting a `null` result and get the string result instead:

```
gremlin> if(nL != null)
......1>     "Hey!"
==>Hey!
```

Checkout the [Gremlin Console Tutorial](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/) for some more discussion on auto-iteration.

Comment: Thanks!  I've played around with the tutorials but must have missed that part.  I've found that Gremlin's documentation is of two types - the simpler, tutorial stuff, and the API itself.  Is there another reference that explains things in more detail without just having to rtfm?

Comment: Interesting question. I know the reference doc is huge and the tutorial is perhaps a bit hard to find. What did you have in mind in terms of filling the documentation gap? Might be better to carry on this conversation on the gremlin-users mailing list instead of SO comments.

Comment: Good idea, I'll check the mailing list.  I'm primarily interested in including Gremlin in a Java project.  I'd do it in Groovy, too, I guess.  Ultimately, I need to be able to get the results of my Gremlin queries out into a program to do things with them, and I can't see a way to do that at the moment that is easy